# Make this code shorter without using loops

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import random
a = random.randrange(1,100)
b = random.randrange(1,100)
c = random.randrange(1,100)
d = random.randrange(1,100)
e = random.randrange(1,100)
print('Random numbers: ',a,b,c,d,e)
sumEven = 0
sumOdd = 0
print("Even numbers: ")
if (a%2)==0:
    sumEven = sumEven+a
    print(a,end=" ")
if (b%2)==0:
    sumEven = sumEven+b
    print(b,end=" ")
if (c%2)==0:
    sumEven = sumEven+c
    print(c,end=" ")
if (d%2)==0:
    sumEven = sumEven+d
    print(d,end=" ")
if (e%2)==0:
    sumEven = sumEven+e
    print(e,end=" ")
print("\nOdd numbers: ")
if (a%2)!=0:
    sumOdd = sumOdd+a
    print(a,end=" ")
if (b%2)!=0:
    sumOdd = sumOdd+b
    print(b,end=" ")
if (c%2)!=0:
    sumOdd = sumOdd+c
    print(c,end=" ")
if (d%2)!=0:
    sumOdd = sumOdd+d
    print(d,end=" ")
if (e%2)!=0:
    sumOdd = sumOdd+e
    print(e,end=" ")

    print("\nSum of all even numbers: ",sumEven)
    print("Sum of all odd numbers:", sumOdd)
```

Please make it shorter suggest shorter code, but without using loops the purpose of the program is to separate odd numbers from even numbers and get the sum of all odd numbers also get the sum of all even numbers

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? One obvious thing, even without loops: why check both e.g. `(a % 2) == 0` **and** `(a % 2) != 0`?

Comment: Loops and lists would make this much simpler. Why the artificial restriction? Without loops, you could use a function but that gain won't be as big.

Answer (score 2):

## Here is the way without explicitly usage of loops:

Here is example with your variables

```
lst = [a,b,c,d,e]
ev = [x for x in lst if x%2 == 0]
od = [x for x in lst if x%2 != 0]
print('Even numbers: ', ev, 'Sum:', sum(ev))
print('odd numbers:',od, 'Sum:', sum(od))
```

or in more appropriate way:

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.random.randint(1,100, 5)
ev = [x for x in lst if x%2 == 0]
od = [x for x in lst if x%2 != 0]
print('Even numbers: ', ev, 'Sum:', sum(ev))
print('odd numbers:',od, 'Sum:', sum(od))
```

## Here is the way without even comprehension usage:

Here is example with your variables:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([a,b,c,d,e])
print('Array:',arr)
print('Even numbers: ', arr[arr%2==0], 'Sum:', sum(arr[arr%2==0]))
print('Odd numbers:',arr[arr%2!=0], 'Sum:', sum(arr[arr%2!=0]))

Out[1]:
Array: [48  9 11 51  6]
Even numbers:  [48  6] Sum: 54
Odd numbers: [ 9 11 51] Sum: 71
```

or in more appropriate way:

```
arr = np.random.randint(1,100, 5)
print('Array:',arr)
print('Even numbers: ', arr[arr%2==0], 'Sum:', sum(arr[arr%2==0]))
print('Odd numbers:',arr[arr%2!=0], 'Sum:', sum(arr[arr%2!=0]))

Out[2]:
Array: [77 57  8 38 67]
Even numbers:  [ 8 38] Sum: 46
Odd numbers: [77 57 67] Sum: 201
```